# SQLite Join Tables With Different Primary Key Values

Tags: database, sqlite

I have two tables in SQLITE one table `FastData` records data at a high rate while the other table `SlowData` records data at a lower rate. `FastData` and `SlowData` share a primary key (`PK`) that represents time of data capture. As such the two tables could look like:

```
Fast Data         Slow Data
Pk   Value1       Pk   Value2
2    1            1    1
3    2            4    2
5    3            7    3
6    4
7    5
9    6
```

I would like to create a Select statement that joins these two tables filling in the `SlowData` with the previous captured data.

```
Join Data         
Pk   Value1  Value2
2    1       1
3    2       1
5    3       2
6    4       2
7    5       3
9    6       3
```

Comment: The Best I have currently is just using the Left Join
`Select FastData.PK, FastData.Value1, Slowdata.Value2`
`From FastData`
`Left Join SlowData ON FastData.PK = SlowData.PK`
`Order By FastData.PK`

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following approach which uses `row_number` to determine the most recent entry as it relates to `Pk` as the ideal entry for `Value2` after performing a left join.

```
SELECT 
    Pk,
    Value1,
    Value2
FROM (
    SELECT
        f.Pk,
        f.Value1,
        s.Value2,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY  f.Pk, f.Value1
            ORDER BY s.Pk DESC
        ) rn
    FROM
        fast_data f
    LEFT JOIN
        slow_data s ON f.Pk >= s.Pk
) t
WHERE rn=1;
```

| Pk | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 2 |
| 6 | 4 | 2 |
| 7 | 5 | 3 |
| 9 | 6 | 3 |

---

[View working demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/39ppRTM3oSpZWK8dNcp1v7/0)

Answer (score 0):

You need a `LEFT` join of the tables and `FIRST_VALUE()` window function to pick `Value2`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.Pk, f.Value1,
       FIRST_VALUE(s.Value2) OVER (PARTITION BY f.Pk ORDER BY s.Pk DESC) Value2
FROM FastData f LEFT JOIN SlowData s
ON s.Pk <= f.Pk;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=4fcf6f4dc371cdff99b0874f0f2adfe7).